# Trying to change chart border color using vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a vba code to try to change the border of a chart based on a separate cell's value.
I got the code to work before when changing the color of a shape but now it's not working anymore. Any ideas?
The code I'm using is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("C62") >= 1 Then
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Select
Selection.Chart.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
Else
If Range("C62") >= 0.95 And Range("C62") < 1 Then
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Select
Selection.Chart.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
Else
If Range("C62") < 0.95 Then
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Select
Selection.Chart.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 20, 60)
End If
End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(62, 3).Select
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain "not working anymore". Reading [ask] and [repro] should help you to improve your question. Also [it's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is worth reading

Comment: I get an run-time error '438', and when I open the code to debug, line 8 is highlighted.

Comment: does "chart 16" exist?

Comment: It does exist yes.

Comment: Does it help to combine these two lines
`ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Select`
`Selection.Chart.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)`
to this
`ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Chart.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)`